# Getting error on aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin

Tags: amazon-web-services

In the beginning, this command worked. But, now it is not working.

```
aws configure
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

output is:

```
An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

aws cli version is:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.2.41 Python/3.8.8 Linux/4.15.0-101-generic exe/x86_64.linuxmint.19 prompt/off
```

When I use different computer with same access-key and secret-key, following command works:

```
aws configure
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

output was:

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

So, I think access-key and secret-key are fine. And, there is something wrong with aws-cli configuration. I have also tried reinstalling aws-cli but no success.
Source I used to reinstall aws-cli:
[reinstall aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html)

OS in which it's not working: `Linux Mint 19`
OS in which it worked: `Ubuntu 20.04`

Comment: Maybe you have your system clock not in sync with aws clocks?

Comment: What happens if you run only ```aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2``` on the Linux mint computer?

Comment: @Nick it shows error: `An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid`

Comment: @marcin sorry for rookie question. how should I manage aws clock? I followed steps from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html what should I do next?

Comment: In that case @Marcin is right, the most likely cause is that you need to sync your clock.

Comment: Check if your system clock is for your own computer, not ec2 instance. Maybe it has incorrect time/date.

Comment: @Marcin on running `chronyc tracking`, it shows `System time     : 0.000803535 seconds slow of NTP time` and `Ref time (UTC)  : Sat Sep 25 02:50:19 2021` but googling "current utc time", it shows `2:55 am Saturday, 25 September 2021 UTC`. so there is a 5min lag. n i am using ecr n ecs. no ec2. what should I now to match them.

Comment: @Marcin I think Ref time(UTC) has some other meaning. It's not changing at all.

Comment: @Marcin followed this: https://realguess.net/2016/08/09/fixing-authorization-failure-in-aws-cli-by-synchronizing-the-clock/ still no success. I am very confused with this time related concepts. There are 3 things: AWS server, AWS CLI, and my computer. so, what is the flow for authenticating `aws ecr`. please explain a little bit in simple words. n what's role of ntp, chronyc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was running `aws ecr` command in root user which was not giving proper error message.

When I run `aws ecr` command in public user, then it gave a proper error message, i.e., `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock`; So, I changed the permission of this file `docker.sock` from user root to public user and group docker to docker using command:
`chown myPublicUser:docker /var/run/docker.sock`

Now, run `aws ecr` using public user, it should work.